# JaCoCo coverage report not displayed in Sonarqube 5.3

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I am able to integrate JaCoCo plugin and I can see the coverage report in Sonar 5.3 when I run

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

but whereas when I run it from Jenkins it uploads the metrics to Sonar without the coverage report and displays this message

> This component does not have coverage details.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? Below is a snippet of my Sonar properties in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>
           ` 

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure a coverage report is generated by the Jenkins job?

Comment: There's a newer version of jacoco-maven-plugin, it's 0.7.8. Also, as the previous commenter has suggested, you need to run jacoco before you run the sonar goal. This generates the files that will be used. Add a maven task for: clean jacoco:prepare-agent test jacoco:report, and then another one after for sonar

Comment: It doesn't generate a coverage report from my jenkins but generates one when i run it from my windows machine.

Comment: @Goibniu I have the prepare-agent and report in my pom.xml. Do i still need to pass those when i run my jenkins job?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. From my understanding sonar needs to be run separately from all other goals, so that's why we have them as separate tasks. Try doing that, comment out the executions and add a maven task in jenkins to run those goals for you, and then a second task to run the sonar goal (don't do a clean before that one!)